# align text in tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to put some text above a figure in beamer like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=top ,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=60mm,height=110pt]{./chapter6/figures_susy/RankingMET08.eps}};
            \node[align=top west,black] at (image.center) {TEXT HERE};
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

but the text appears in the middle of the plot - How can I make align the text to the top of the figure?

Comment: Do you want to use TikZ or it's just a try?

Comment: sure want to use tikz...and also if is possible to get two figures in the same line, each one with its own text above the pic

Comment: @Alex I think the question is if you are using tikz anyway then using this is fine but for just the stated use it is a gigantic sledgehammer to crack a nut. you could for example just use `\begin{tabular}{c}text\\ \includegraphics{..}\end{tabular}\begin{tabular}{c}text\\ \includegraphics{..}\end{tabular}` to put two text/graphic pairs on a line

Answer (score 7):

You have some mistakes. `anchor=top` should be `anchor=north`. `top` doesn't exist. Similarly `align=top west` should be `align=left`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=north,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=60mm,height=110pt]{example-image}};
            \node[align=left,black,anchor=south] at (image.north) {TEXT HERE};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We will now put two figures in same line. I have changed the figure width to 3cm to make them smaller and added `keepaspectratio` to prevent them from distorting. Adjust figure width and `4cm` in `right=4cm of image1` to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=north,inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=110pt,keepaspectratio]{example-image}};
            \node[align=left,black,anchor=south] at (image1.north) {TEXT HERE};
            %% second figure Change 4cm appropriately.
            \node[anchor=north,inner sep=0,right=4cm of image1] (image2) {\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=110pt,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
            \node[align=left,black,anchor=south] at (image2.north) {TEXT HERE};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use 2 `tikzpicture`s side by side.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=north,inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=110pt,keepaspectratio]{example-image}};
            \node[align=left,black,anchor=south] at (image1.north) {TEXT HERE};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
%\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}            
            \node[anchor=north,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=40mm,height=110pt,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
            \node[align=left,black,anchor=south] at (image2.north) {TEXT HERE};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need to use `align=left` and `black`, right?

Comment: @KevinC Probably. But the OP used `top west` and to correct that I put this in and it creeped in all examples :-).